# sprintf to reverse an int and store as char

Tags: c, string

I"m trying to store int array as a str and display it but in the reverse order.
Its only while printing the str that i get junk.

What is wrong in my code?

```
int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // Output should be 321 (char)
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    char str[size + 1];
    int i;
    for (size = size - 1; size >= 0; size--) {
        sprintf(&str[size], "%d", a[size]);
        //printf("%c\n", str[size]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", str); // I get garbage.
}
```

Comment: There are so many wrongs here, it's hard to enumerate them all. To start with - it won't work if any of the integer values is larger than 9 or smaller than 0. Second, you are not doing anything in reverse order here (except for the direction of the loop). Third, you are attempting to copy single-character strings into your output `str`. At the end of each copy operation, `sprintf` adds a null character, so when you're done, `str` stores `"1\0\0\0"`, which would be printed as `1`. BTW, what is `int i` for?

Comment: Don't define unused variables such as `i` — and don't hide variable declarations on the same line as other variable declarations.

Comment: You can use `snprintf` without any storage to determine the length of each integer in your array by looping and using something like: `nchar += snprintf (NULL, 0, "%d", a[i]);` to accumulate the total length of the integers and then add `+1` to provide storage for the *nul-terminating* character.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your solution with several bug fixes.  For starters, you can't assume that your integer array will only hold single digit values.

And that for loop as you have it:

```
for(size=size-1;size >= 0;size--)
```

Is very suspicious looking. (the index variable is the thing its based off?)

**Simple solution**

This is likely what you meant:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sprintf(&str[i],"%d", a[size-1-i]);
}
str[size] = '\0';
```

Or this:

```
str[size] = '\0';
for(i = size-1; i <= 0; i--) {
    sprintf(&str[i],"%d", a[size-1-i]);
}
```

**Better solution**

I'm not sure what you are expecting to do if an integer within the `a` array is negative. So the `-` sign will just get inserted into `str` inplace.

The solution I have will first count how many chars are needed for each integer in `a`.  Then it will allocate the `str` buffer with that length (+1 for null char).

Then we make use of the return value from `sprintf` to figure out where to concatenate onto.  We could use `strcat`, but this is likely faster.

```
int main() {

    int j = 0;
    int a[] = { 1,2,3 }; // Output should be 321 (char)

    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    int length = 1; // +1 for final null char

    // Count the size of characters needed for each integer
    // Do a dummy sprintf and use its return value to figure out how many chars are needed
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char tmp[sizeof(int) * 5];  // sizeof(int)*5 is big enough to hold any integer including a negative value
        length += sprintf(tmp, "%d", a[i]);  // utilize the return value from sprintf and add it to the running length
    }

    char str[length];
    str[0] = '\0'; // initially null terminate our string

    // reverse print chars from a into str
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {  // use i as index variable, not size
        j += sprintf(str + j, "%d", a[size - 1 - i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your right but this is only a sample dataset that I'm trying to use and the purpose was to understand why I cannot directly write to the address of the index . I'm actually trying to understand the need for the 'length' and 'j' vars you've used

Comment: The code in the question was clearly written by a very novice C programmer, making your extremely elaborated answer way too complex for this dude to grasp (and again - it all stems from the problem definition to begin with).

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica: You must have missed my point in that case.

Comment: Ok - I've updated the answer with a "simple solution" that will work for arrays of single digit solutions. Then a more correct solution that will work better for all types of integers.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica: Not sure what you mean by "went off" here, but if this by any means implies that my comment refers to this answer in a negative connotation, then it was not at all my intention (thought I made it pretty clear along the way). Maybe you oughtta read it through again (the last few sentences in particular). To summarize the main point (which seems to have eluded you) - for the given question, it is virtually impossible to provide a good answer from which the person who asked it (let alone the rest of the community) would actually benefit.

Comment: @rkhshm you need the `length` so you can either size a VLA (*Variable Length Array*) or allocate storage for your reversed array of integer values concatenated into a character string.

Comment: @goodvibration The *"went off"* was due to the intentionally derogatory and degrading suggestion that the answer posted was `"To indulge yourself when you see that green icon at the top of the page, indicating that you've got an extra 10 points."` That is entirely uncalled for.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica: Simple contextual deduction: this dude most likely doesn't understand the difference between statically-allocated arrays, dynamically-allocated arrays and variable-length arrays. Moreover, it doesn't seem like the type of knowledge that he should care about at this point (i.e., there are several much more basic things to be learned here prior to that). With regards to that gray part in your comment above - you're right, I could have probably made a better wording choice here.

Comment: I know, but you gotta start somewhere and introduce aspects of the language to "lead that horse to water", then work on "making him drink". There are only so many ways to provide storage for a character array on the fly. The only way you simplify the answer is to assume all integer values will only be a single-digit. Which will likely draw the ire of reviewing programmers as that constraint also wasn't stated in the question. I don't see anything but a very basic approach in the answer which is what made me curious of how you would write up an answer of your own.

Comment: @goodvibration and David - Guys, please cool it.  There is the answer the OP **wants** to hear which is the simple solution to his immediate bug.  And then there is the answer the OP **needs** to hear which is an improvement to his algorithm for perf and robustness.  If I had just started with the simple solution, the answer would have surely been downvoted as being incomplete and buggy. So I went straight for the formal solution.  I've since added back the simple solution to solve the initial bug.  Hopefully the OP will take advantage of both solutions and learn from both.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, closer to original posts, and clearly not trying to address the general problem (assume values are single digit):

```
    int a[]={1,2,3}; // Output should be 321 (char)
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    char str[size+1];
    for(int i=0; i<size ; i++) {
        str[size-1-i] = ‘0’ + a[i];
    }
    str[size] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", str); // I get garbage.
}
```

Taking advantage of the assumed input value, converting each int to character representation at the reverse position.